# spacing between list and equation

Tags: spacing

my code is

```
\item Discuss to what extent the cable length affects the peak voltage at node C. 
\end{enumerate}

\begin{center}
\begin{align*}
 H(t) = 0 \ for\ t < 0 \\
 H(t) = 1 \ for\ t \geq 0
 \end{align*}
 \end{center}
```

[image: Output is as]

How can i minimize the space between the list and equation?Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why the `center` environment?  Displayed equations are centered by default.

Comment: You should never have a blank line before a displayed equation, and certainly never put it in `center` each of those would create spurious space, and you have both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be

```
\item Discuss to what extent the cable length affects the peak voltage at node C. 
\begin{align*}
 H(t) = 0 &\text{ for } t < 0 \\
 H(t) = 1 & \text{for } t \geq 0
 \end{align*}
 \end{enumerate}
```

Don't have a blank line before a displayed equation or put it in a display environment such as `center` also don't have `align` with  no alignment points (`&` and don't have words like `for` in math italic.  Probably it would be better to use `cases` rather than `align*`/

Comment: Thanks, i am just a beginner. It works.Can i also ask you another question. I have been translating document in Microsoft word to latex and i have some figures that is blurred (i.e. i have use snipping tool or just copied from the file. Can you give me some suggestion for this problem or suggest me some drawing platform for latex which is easy and more efficient.